# Could one leave / migrate away from Canada after making citizenship application

Tags: canada, citizenship

I have a specific question on Canada citizenship.
If somebody have spent required amount of residency years on PR & satisfied requirements for application for Canadaian citizenship.
I read that- after making application for citizenship it could take upto one year.

In that case, after making an application, is he/she able to leave Canada / move-away?

In that case, how the citizenship interview & citizenship ceremony/ update communication will work?

Kindly throw some light on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave Canada after submitting your citizenship application.

If you need to leave Canada and want to stay eligible for Canadian citizenship, you must:

- make sure that you live in Canada long enough to keep your Permanent Resident (PR) status
- be a permanent resident (when you apply)
- not lose PR status before you take the Oath of Citizenship
- bring your PR card with you when you leave Canada so you can return easily

Appointments and other events, like your: citizenship test (for applicants 18 to 54 years of age), interview ceremony, must take place in Canada.

Source: https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=911&top=5